# Detecting when phone call present iphone objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c

Is there a way to detect if a phone call is going on on a phone in objective c? You'll notice many views move downwards under this situation and as such I want to know when.

Comment: I assume you mean the green banner that appears. Don't forget that there is a blue one when using navigation, and a red one when recording audio. So you don't just want to detect when on a phone call. Why do you need to know this anyway? If you do your UI correctly, it will automatically adjust to the smaller screen size.

Comment: I'm making a custom camera view. So I've been doing a massive amount of hard coded hacking... You think I could do it by putting things at h*.5, for example, and then h would adjust? By the way h would be self.view.frame.size.height... I guess that makes sense. I just wasn't sure what kind of transforms phone calls etc. do to the view.

Comment: Is there any way to detect if at any time (a boolean check), not when the call comes through?? Many view controllers that need to know this aren't aloc inited yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not be detecting calls with the status bar frame. Instead you can detect phone calls with `NSNotification` like this

Put this in you `viewDidLoad`:

```
#import <CoreTelephony/CTCall.h>

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(callReceived:) name:CTCallStateIncoming object:nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(callEnded:) name:CTCallStateDisconnected object:nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(callConnected:) name:CTCallStateConnected object:nil];
```

And don't forget to add `CoreTelephony.framework`

Comment: You do not want to do this.

Answer (score -1):

As explained by rmaddy, if you're trying to catch status bar frame changes, detecting phone calls is not the best way.

What you can do is implement the methods `- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application willChangeStatusBarFrame:(CGRect)newStatusBarFrame` and `- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didChangeStatusBarFrame:(CGRect)oldStatusBarFrame` of your app delegate or listen for the `UIApplicationWillChangeStatusBarFrameNotification` and `UIApplicationDidChangeStatusBarFrameNotification` notifications.